# What is the purpose of "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" option in PHPMyAdmin Export

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In the custom options of PHPMyAdmin export feature, there is an option named "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" which is unchecked by default. Could you let me know the purpose of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it if you would like it to add a `use database-name;` statement to the sql file you export. This is so when you import it, phpMyAdmin will know which database to use for the rest of the sql statements.